# Data sync solution

Tags: windows, backup, file-synchronization

Dear SoftwareRecs community,

I'm currently looking for a data transfer solution in an internal network for large amounts of data (thousands of files, as well as 100s of GBs of camera data). The program should synchronize an entire folder and all of its contents from a source computer to a different computer - specifically its RAID hard drives. Both computers are located in the same network, respectively. After the transfer is completed, the folder will be deleted manually on the source computer, but should of course still be backed up on the RAID system.

I've been looking into SyncToy and Robocopy so far as they are solutions by Microsoft, where the main caveat I found was that it doesn't check whether a file is currently still opened by another process (such as when the image is still being written to disk from the source), causing file corruption and loss of data.

The software doesn't have to be freeware necessarily as long as it works. Suggestions are greatly appreciated!